# Retriving the values of Map inside List

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>()
```

I have an array list which contains an hashmap, i am able to get the position of my List , now how would i get the key `and` value of the object in my List.

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView() {        
    System.out.println(data.get(position)); // i am getting my List Objects 
}
```

// The below is the output of `data.get(position)`

```
 {"title":"hello"}, => 0 
 {"title":"hello1"}, => 1
 {"title":"hello2"}, => 2
 {"title":"hello3"}, => 3
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve, but it *looks* like you've chosen the wrong data structure. What are you actually trying to model? Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: Very unclear question.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I don't think this structure is correct but that's how I picked up the project module =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little modification in above code.Please find the below code snippets.

```
public class Test01 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> map=new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("test_key", "test_value");
    data.add(map);
    HashMap hashMap = data.get(0);
    Iterator<Object> iterator=hashMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry=(Entry<String, Object>) iterator.next();
        System.out.println("Key :"+entry.getKey()+" Value : "+entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

}

i hope this may be help...

Answer (score 3):

Try this out :

```
List<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    for (Map element : list) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet = element.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> mapEntry : entrySet) {
            System.out.println("Key is : " + mapEntry.getKey());
            System.out.println("Value is : " + mapEntry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With full example try this:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map1.put("title", "hello");
map2.put("title2", "hello2");
list.add(map2);
list.add(map1);

HashMap<String, Object> innerMap;

         for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
         {
              innerMap = list.get(i);           

             for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : innerMap.entrySet())
             {
                 System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question leaves much to be desired, but I believe this is what you're looking for

```
public class HashMapClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        //Get the Hasmap at position
        HashMap map = data.get(position);

        //Get the data in a the hashmap
        Object obj = map.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Map.Entry

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Y {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Your data structure...
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        //Add some dummy data
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("1", "A");
        map.put("2", "B");
        map.put("3", "C");

        //Add the Map to the List
        list.add(map);

        int positionInList = 0; //Manipulate this how you want

        //Use Map.Entry to access both key and value
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : list.get(positionInList).entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```